# Cassandra - deleted data still there

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra version: 1.2.6. Single node.

I've deleted the data from table

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE symbol = 'symbol1' AND field = 'field1';
```

and the following query does not return it:

`SELECT symbol, ts, value FROM mytable WHERE symbol IN ('symbol1');`

However, some different, more restrictive queries still return the old (deleted) data:

```
SELECT symbol, ts, value FROM mytable WHERE symbol IN ('symbol1') AND field='field1' AND ts >= '2013-09-04 00:00:00+0000' AND ts <= '2014-09-25 00:00:00+0000';
```

The data didn't reappear instantly but only after around 5-10 minutes, after few additional rows were added to the table for that symbol/field.

I've run: `nodetool repair mykeyspace`

But it didn't help. Any ideas how to fix it?

Schema of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  symbol text,
  field text,
  ts timestamp,
  value double,
  PRIMARY KEY (symbol, field, ts)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

Comment: It appears running a major compaction did help.
nodetool compact mykeyspace
Should I be running major compaction manually from time to time?

Comment: Do you use 2ndary indexes?

Comment: @Mikhail Stepura, no secondary indexes. This is entire table definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem, fixed in 1.2.19 along with a couple of other tombstone issues, sounds like the one you're having: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7810

If you're willing to experiment, would you consider upgrading? There are quite a few changes/fixes for Cassandra 1.2.x related to deleted data: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-1.2/CHANGES.txt

Comment: Thanks a a lot @catpows. I've learned a lot about Cassandra today!

Answer (score 1):

Deleting in Cassandra is radically different from, say RDBMS. I highly recommend reading [Datastax Documentation : About Deletes](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html).

Comment: Thanks Chiron, I've read this document. Yet I still don't understand why the data reappeared and most important how to stop it from happening again.

Comment: dead link, link only answer.